# Is the phrase "didn't miss the target by too far" grammatical/idiomatic?

Tags: idioms, prepositional-phrases, comparative-constructions

I thought this was a common phrase, but it has [0 Google results.](https://www.google.com.tw/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1ASUC_enTW628TW628&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22%20miss%20the%20target%20*%20too%20far%22)

Example sentence:

> He was wrong about calling her mentally sick. However, he hadn't
>   missed the target by too far.

If the phrase isn't grammatical/idiomatic, what's a better option?

Comment: The reason you didn't get any results is partly because *to hit/miss a target* is usually a "binary outcome" situation (you either hit the target or you don't). It's meaningful to say you *didn't miss a target by far* (you definitely missed it, but not by much), but if you *didn't miss it by **too** far* that tends to imply you were ***close enough*** (i.e. - you did in fact "succeed" - it's just that the target was imprecisely defined). The problem (such as it is) is in the *semantics*, not the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your phrase is grammatical (I might say *didn't miss the target by too **much***), and I imagine that most people would understand its meaning, however I'm not so sure about *idiomatic* - at the very least, other idioms would be more commonly used.

A *very* similar idiom that's often used in English is ***not (so/too) far off the mark*** - in other words, not far away from the target. For example.

> He was wrong about calling her mentally ill. However, He **wasn't too far off the mark.**

(as a side note, we tend to refer to people as being '*mentally *ill*', rather than 'mentally *sick*')

A variant of this is ***wide of the mark***, e.g.

> He was wrong about calling her mentally ill. However, He **wasn't too wide of the mark.**

Answer (score 1):

a more common alternative (according too [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=he+wasn%27t+totally+wrong&rlz=1C1CHBD_enMA720MA720&oq=he+wasn%27t+totally+wrong&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59l2j69i64l2.1453j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)):

"...,he wasn't totally wrong".

So, to avoid the repetition, but keep the antithesis, the sentence could become like:

"He wasn't right about calling her mentally sick. Although, he wasn't totally wrong"